# Angular ng-repeat is crashing the browsers for my emoji's - Angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an module that is used to load emoji's in Angular - this works however I want to be able have a simple function to load all of them at once in a single `<div>` or `<textarea>`

The code is too long to add here - it is in a gist here
https://gist.github.com/gkimpson/280989a698e591faab4072570edb9e60

When I run some code within my partial as follows it crashes my browser within 5-10 seconds

```
<div ng-repeat="emoji in emojis">
  {{ addEmojiTest(emoji.code) }}
</div>
```

Can someone suggest a way to optimise this and not crash everything?

Comment: can you reproduce this on a fiddle?

Comment: You could consider using the ng-bind attribute which should be slightly more effective than using the {{ }} data binding: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Also consider manipulating the array of objects before using ng-repeat. That way you don't have to call addEmojiTest inline which is a bad practice.

Comment: I just checked your code, addEmojiTest doesn't return any value. You should not set a scope var, you should be returning a value so the view gets updated.